# How to use Map function in react js with Api using Hooks like useEffect and useState

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, api, mern

Hi l am new to react and started to learn something new. I am actually stuck in a situation where I know how the solution can be achieved but I do not know the implementation part.

I Am trying to use API using Await Async and show data in my card. I can see results on the console log but not in the card.

I think as far as I know, I have to use map function to map the data with my card to see all data. Please correct me if wrong.

Also if you can let me know what needs to be done next looking at my code and how will be great.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {
  Button,
  Card,
  CardActionArea,
  CardActions,
  CardContent,
  CardMedia,
} from "@material-ui/core";

const cardStyle = {
  cardMain: {
    maxWidth: "300px",
    maxHeight: "300px",
    margin: "10px",
  },

  cardImage: {
    height: "150px",
    backgroundImage:
      "url(" +
      "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1517971129774-8a2b38fa128e?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80" +
      ")",
    marginLeft: "7px",
    marginRight: "7px",
    marginTop: "5px",
  },
};

const Produts = () => {
  const [movieData, setMovieData] = useState([]);

  const getMovieList = async () => {
    const url =
      "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=myapikey&query=Avengers";

    const response = await fetch(url);
    try {
      const responseJson = await response.json();
      console.log(responseJson);
      setMovieData = responseJson.results;
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getMovieList();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <Card style={cardStyle.cardMain}>
        <CardActionArea>
          {setMovieData.original_title}
          <CardMedia style={cardStyle.cardImage}>
            {setMovieData.original_image}
          </CardMedia>
          <CardContent>{setMovieData.original_date}</CardContent>
        </CardActionArea>
        <CardActions style={cardStyle.cardButton}>
          <Button>Watch</Button>
          <Button>Like</Button>
          <Button>Rent</Button>
        </CardActions>
      </Card>
    </>
  );
};

export default Produts;
```

Any help or suggestion is really appreciated.

Comment: Why did you write `setMovieData = (responseJson.results)`? Specifically, why the equals sign? `setMovieData` is a function that you call, to update state. See https://daveceddia.com/usestate-hook-examples/

Comment: `setMovieData` is a function. so pass results as an argument - `setMovieData(responseJson.results)`. also in your jsx code, ie inside return, you should use `movieData` which contains the actual values and not the `setMovieData` which is a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const Produts = () => {
  const [movieData, setMovieData] = useState([]);
  const getMovieList = async () => {
    const url =
      "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=myapikey&query=Avengers";

    const response = await fetch(url);
    try {
      const responseJson = await response.json();
      const data = responseJson.results;
      setMovieData(data);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getMovieList();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {movieData.map((movie) => {
        return (
          <Card style={cardStyle.cardMain} key={movie.id}>
            <CardActionArea>
              {movie.original_title}
              <CardMedia style={cardStyle.cardImage}>CardMedia</CardMedia>
              <CardContent>cardContainer</CardContent>
            </CardActionArea>
            <CardActions style={cardStyle.cardButton}>
              <Button>Watch</Button>
              <Button>Like</Button>
              <Button>Rent</Button>
            </CardActions>
          </Card>
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
};

export default Produts;
```

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```js
const Produts = () => {
  const [movieData, setMovieData] = useState([]);

  const getMovieList = async () => {
    const url =
      "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=myapikey&query=Avengers";

    const response = await fetch(url);
    try {
      const responseJson = await response.json();
      console.log(responseJson);
      setMovieData(responseJson.results);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getMovieList();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      movieData.map ((movie) => (
      <Card style={cardStyle.cardMain}>
        <CardActionArea>
          {movie.original_title}
          <CardMedia style={cardStyle.cardImage}>
            {movie.original_image}
          </CardMedia>
          <CardContent>{movie.original_date}</CardContent>
        </CardActionArea>
        <CardActions style={cardStyle.cardButton}>
          <Button>Watch</Button>
          <Button>Like</Button>
          <Button>Rent</Button>
        </CardActions>
      </Card>
      ))
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks a million, will surely try it and see if it works sir @nokwiw

Answer (score 1):

First of all you are using the useState wrong try this way setMovieData(responseJson.results) and next use this for map

```
<div>
  { movieDate.map(movie =>{
    <Card style={ cardStyle.cardMain }>
      <CardActionArea>{ movie .original_title }
      < CardMedia style = { cardStyle.cardImage } > { movie .original_image } < /CardMedia>
        < CardContent > { movie .original_date } < /CardContent>

        < /CardActionArea>
        < CardActions style = { cardStyle.cardButton } >
          <Button>Watch < /Button>
          < Button > Like < /Button>
          < Button > Rent < /Button>
          < /CardActions>
          < /Card>}
  })
        < /div>
```

Comment: Thanks a million, @Rahul it really helped me to understand the concept of useState in real terms when and where to use it.